# UUID.randomUUID() does not give unique values

Tags: uuid

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

I got the same uuid generated at multiple places. Can anybody help me how to avoid it ?

It is affecting my functionality that I am working on where I need it to be unique everytime.

Comment: `I got the same uuid generated at multiple places` ... _highly_ unlikely.  Please add the relevant Java code to your question.

Comment: the issue is resolved now. I was not clearing my previous stored uuid and thus the previous one was getting retreived . Thanks, it is generating unique uuid now . we made necessary changes required(in my code implementaion where we are clearing off the last stored uuid once used).

Answer (score 0):

Try this package

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-random]

You can use this to generate various UUIDs